# Cron jobs delayed because of one super long one

Tags: php, laravel, cron

So I have cron jobs running every minute. These cron jobs all finish within 30 seconds. However, my last cron job is random and only starts working when it finds the data in the system. Sometimes there is a lot of data and the cron job usually takes about 10 minutes to finish, which I am perfectly fine with. However, once this cron job initiates and the minute passes, the other cron jobs aren't started until the cron job is done. So I have about 15+ cron jobs waiting for that one cron job to finish and then they start up again.

I used withoutOverlapping and it doesn't seem to work? Is there a solution?
Here is a list of my jobs:

```
    $schedule->command('sms:schedule')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('sms:sendbulk')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('sms:notifyevent')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('voice:sendbulk')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('email:sendbulk')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('email:schedule')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('voice:schedule')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('sms:sendrecurringsms')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('sms:sendrecurringvoice')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('email:sendrecurringemail')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('event:recurring')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('senderid:validation')->dailyAt('12:01');
    $schedule->command('invoice:recurring')->dailyAt('12:01');
    $schedule->command('reports:daily')->dailyAt('06:00');
    $schedule->command('checksms:status')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('checkroom:status')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('location:minute')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('location:checkcircle')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('recurring:setsmsname')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('recurring:setvoicename')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('site:schedulingevents')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('sms:contactnameset')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('daily:checklocation')->withoutOverlapping();
```

That last one is the one that has differentiating times. But I need the other ones to keep running every minute if that is the case.

Comment: So others aren't running or what?

Comment: Yeah so they will run until that last one picks something up and then starts running. Once the last one starts running, they all wait till it is done, which could be up to 10 minutes.. @Viney